# Record IDs are seemingly changed on CI server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, continuous-integration, circleci

I'm using CircleCI in order to run my tests. I'm running into a strange phenomena from test code that looks like this:

```rb
record1_id = create(:record, ...).id
record2_id = create(:record, ...).id
record3_id = create(:record, ....).id

puts "Created the following records... #{ record1_id }, #{ record2_id }, #{ record3_id }"
puts "Total records in DB right now... #{ Record.count }"

# Test call
puts "About to execute lookup"
record_ids = subject.call(params)
puts "Received back record ids... #{ record_ids }"

expect(record_ids).to include(record1_id)
expect(record_ids).to include(record2_id)
expect(record_ids).to include(record3_id)
```

When run locally, it's fine. However when run in a parallel CircleCI setup, the tests fail sporadically and I see this output:

> Created the following records... 1018350864, 1018350865, 1018350866
>
> Total records in DB right now... 3
>
> About to execute lookup...
>
> Received back record ids... [980191033, 980191032, 980191031]

How could this be happening? I've tried to clear the Rails query cache, retrying the test, but this test still manages to fail with a DB query that returns me to what seem to be correct records... but with totally different IDs?

`subject.call` does a `Record.find_by_sql(query, params...)` with query that looks like this:

```
      SELECT * FROM records
      INNER JOIN joins ON records.joins_id = joins.id
      WHERE records.status IN (:active_statuses) AND (
           :phone_number IN (SELECT phone FROM users WHERE records.pickup_contact_id = users.id)
        OR :phone_number IN (SELECT phone FROM users WHERE records.dropoff_contact_id = users.id)
        OR :phone_number IN (SELECT phone FROM users WHERE records.user_id = users.id)
      )
      ORDER BY records.updated_at DESC
      LIMIT 100
```

Comment: What does `subject.call` do?

Comment: It calls `find_by_sql` with a query I just posted in question

Comment: Looks a bit odd that you're doing `select * from` and then treating them like ids from then on. I'd expect them to be `Record` instances at that point.

Comment: That could be it... let me give it a shot! Thanks @Shadwell

Comment: What exactly do you run in parallel? And does each spec have a separate DB, or is it a shared one?

Comment: How are you deriving the params and query values?